# Creating WSDL PHP request return internal error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, xsd

I'm having big problem with doing this search request.

First I need to authenticate myself and that is working fine.

Then I need to add security token to request header and that is pretty easy as well.

But when I'm trying to create search request I can get positive response fro the server.

```
$url = 'http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/AirService.svc?wsdl';
$search = new SoapClient($url , array('trace' => true));

$header =  new SoapHeader('http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk','AuthHeader', $token, true);
$search->__setSoapHeaders(array($header)); ?>
<h1>Search</h1> <?php var_dump($search);


$ser_par = array(
    'request'=>array(
            'SelectedAirlines' => array(),
        'MaximumConnectionTimeMins' => '',
        'MaxResultsPerAirline' => '',
        'JourneyDetails' => array(
              'JourneyDetail'=> array(
                'DepartureDateTime' => '2012-12-01T17:20:58',
                'DeparturePoint' => 'LON',
                'DeparturePointIsCity' =>   false,
                'DestinationPoint' => 'MLE',
                'DestinationPointIsCity' => false,
                'ViaPointAirportCode' => ''),
              'JourneyDetail' => array(
                'DepartureDateTime' => '2012-12-15T17:20:58',
                'DeparturePoint' => 'MLE',
                'DeparturePointIsCity' =>   false,
                'DestinationPoint' => 'LON',
                'DestinationPointIsCity' => false,
                'ViaPointAirportCode' => ''
                )),
        'SearchType' => 'Availability',
            'FlexiDays' => 0,
            'FareType' => 'All',
            'SearchSource' =>'Default',
            'ReturnIncompleteResults' => false,
            'SortOrder' => 'Price',
            'ChildPaxCount' => 1,
            'AdultPaxCount' => 1,
            'DirectFlightsOnly' => false,
            'CabinClass' => 'All',
            'InfantWithSeatPaxCount' => 0,
            'InfantPaxCount' => 1,
            'MaxResultsPerAirline' => '',
            'MaxResults' => '',
            'IncludePriorDepartues' => false,
            'SessionID'=> '070ed09a-ec58-4eee-a7d9-31942e968a3c',
));

try{
    $search->Search(array($ser_par));
}catch(SoapFault $e){
    echo '<h1> Errors: </h1>';
        var_dump($e);
}
```

This is output:

```
Search

object(SoapClient)#218 (4) { ["trace"]=> int(1) ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(108) of type (Unknown) ["__default_headers"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(SoapHeader)#219 (4) { ["namespace"]=> string(60) "http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk" ["name"]=> string(10) "AuthHeader" ["data"]=> string(36) "149db61f-c1d6-49e2-bf37-430ec3526053" ["mustUnderstand"]=> bool(true) } } }
Errors:

object(SoapFault)#220 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(433) "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs." ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(96) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-content/themes/responsive/page.php" ["line":protected]=> int(151) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(96) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-content/themes/responsive/page.php" ["line"]=> int(151) ["function"]=> string(6) "__call" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Search" [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["request"]=> array(19) { ["SelectedAirlines"]=> array(0) { } ["MaximumConnectionTimeMins"]=> string(0) "" ["MaxResultsPerAirline"]=> string(0) "" ["JourneyDetails"]=> array(1) { ["JourneyDetail"]=> array(6) { ["DepartureDateTime"]=> string(19) "2012-12-15T17:20:58" ["DeparturePoint"]=> string(3) "MLE" ["DeparturePointIsCity"]=> bool(false) ["DestinationPoint"]=> string(3) "LON" ["DestinationPointIsCity"]=> bool(false) ["ViaPointAirportCode"]=> string(0) "" } } ["SearchType"]=> string(12) "Availability" ["FlexiDays"]=> int(0) ["FareType"]=> string(3) "All" ["SearchSource"]=> string(7) "Default" ["ReturnIncompleteResults"]=> bool(false) ["SortOrder"]=> string(5) "Price" ["ChildPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["AdultPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["DirectFlightsOnly"]=> bool(false) ["CabinClass"]=> string(3) "All" ["InfantWithSeatPaxCount"]=> int(0) ["InfantPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["MaxResults"]=> string(0) "" ["IncludePriorDepartues"]=> bool(false) ["SessionID"]=> string(36) "070ed09a-ec58-4eee-a7d9-31942e968a3c" } } } } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(96) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-content/themes/responsive/page.php" ["line"]=> int(151) ["function"]=> string(6) "Search" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["request"]=> array(19) { ["SelectedAirlines"]=> array(0) { } ["MaximumConnectionTimeMins"]=> string(0) "" ["MaxResultsPerAirline"]=> string(0) "" ["JourneyDetails"]=> array(1) { ["JourneyDetail"]=> array(6) { ["DepartureDateTime"]=> string(19) "2012-12-15T17:20:58" ["DeparturePoint"]=> string(3) "MLE" ["DeparturePointIsCity"]=> bool(false) ["DestinationPoint"]=> string(3) "LON" ["DestinationPointIsCity"]=> bool(false) ["ViaPointAirportCode"]=> string(0) "" } } ["SearchType"]=> string(12) "Availability" ["FlexiDays"]=> int(0) ["FareType"]=> string(3) "All" ["SearchSource"]=> string(7) "Default" ["ReturnIncompleteResults"]=> bool(false) ["SortOrder"]=> string(5) "Price" ["ChildPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["AdultPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["DirectFlightsOnly"]=> bool(false) ["CabinClass"]=> string(3) "All" ["InfantWithSeatPaxCount"]=> int(0) ["InfantPaxCount"]=> int(1) ["MaxResults"]=> string(0) "" ["IncludePriorDepartues"]=> bool(false) ["SessionID"]=> string(36) "070ed09a-ec58-4eee-a7d9-31942e968a3c" } } } } } [2]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(90) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-includes/template-loader.php" ["line"]=> int(43) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(96) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-content/themes/responsive/page.php" } ["function"]=> string(7) "include" } [3]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(77) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-blog-header.php" ["line"]=> int(16) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(90) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-includes/template-loader.php" } ["function"]=> string(12) "require_once" } [4]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(68) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/index.php" ["line"]=> int(17) ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(77) "/home/sites/simplymaldivesholidays.co.uk/public_html/feeds/wp-blog-header.php" } ["function"]=> string(7) "require" } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(433) "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs." ["faultcode"]=> string(22) "a:InternalServiceFault" }
```

Here are only resource files I've got.

Documentation:
http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/documentation/

XML document:
http://devapi.stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/AirService.svc?wsdl

This is sample search request. I've tried to use those values but unsuccessful.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/AirService/IAirService/Search</Action>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk">a80681e2-e70f-4bf0-ab0f-df81a6449c6d</AuthHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Search xmlns="http://stellatravelgateway.stellatravelservices.co.uk/AirService">
      <request SearchType="Availability" FlexiDays="0" FareType="All" SearchSource="Default" ReturnIncompleteResults="false" SortOrder="Price" ChildPaxCount="1" AdultPaxCount="1" DirectFlightsOnly="false" CabinClass="All" InfantWithSeatPaxCount="0" InfantPaxCount="1">
        <SelectedAirlines />
        <MaxResultsPerAirline xsi:nil="true" />
        <JourneyDetails>
          <JourneyDetail DepartureDateTime="2012-12-01T17:20:58" DeparturePoint="LON" DeparturePointIsCity="false" DestinationPoint="MLE" DestinationPointIsCity="false" ViaPointAirportCode="" />
          <JourneyDetail DepartureDateTime="2012-12-15T17:20:58" DeparturePoint="MLE" DeparturePointIsCity="false" DestinationPoint="LON" DestinationPointIsCity="false" ViaPointAirportCode="" />
        </JourneyDetails>
        <MaxResults xsi:nil="true" />
        <IncludePriorDepartues>false</IncludePriorDepartues>
        <SessionID>070ed09a-ec58-4eee-a7d9-31942e968a3c</SessionID>
      </request>
    </Search>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My question is: What I'm doing here wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Best regards
PawikSD

Comment: The response message indicates that it is a server-side error. Do you control the server or is this a 3rd-party service?

Comment: It's 3rd-party service and they do not provide any support for php. All they do is .NET.

Comment: They don't need to support PHP (I have to deal with the same situation pretty often). Give them the SOAP request you're sending, and the response you're getting, when asking for support; the language you use to generate the request is insignificant - that's half the point of SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for help.
I've managed to sort out it. I've used SoapUI to get proper request format. 
Next I've copied it and sent it as curl request.
Works like a charm.
Thanks